# commande console form java

Tags: java

i'm trying to execute 2 commands via java programme with process

```
Process p  = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command1);
Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command2);
```

the problem is that the first one is ok but the seconde on cant be established
it is always bloqed in waitfor()

Comment: `waitFor()` waits for the process to finish execution.  Are you sure the second process is actually designed to finish executing, rather than continue running?

Answer (score 1):

You might be running into the dreaded "need to empty the streams" problem. See [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for details on it.

Also in the same article is some info on other traps you can run into if you're treating getRuntime().exec() like the command line.

Answer (score 1):

When running an external procss that prints anything to stdout/stderr, you should read what it writes - otherwise it will block once it's buffer fills up.
you basically needs a thread to read from stdout and a thread to read from stderr of each process.

Comment: or re-direct your processes stdout to something like /dev/null or a log file